# Javascript: List all variables in the same scope (iframe)

Tags: javascript, iframe, scope, global-variables

I do have some custom code in an iframe, where I declare a *global* variable. Within the iframe there is also third party code, which *globals* I would like to access.

**Question**

Broadly: Is it possible to list all variables, which are in the same scope as another variable?

More specifically: Is it possible to list all global variables in an iframe, if have custom code within it?

**What I've tried**

To list all variables from a certain *scope* I used:

```
var listScopeVars = function(scope) {
    for (var prop in scope) {
        if(scope[prop] && typeof(scope[prop]) != "function") {
            console.log(prop + "=" + scope[prop]);
        }
    }
};
```

From within the iframe I then called:

```
listScopeVars(window); /* throws an cross domain error */
listScopeVars(document); 
listScopeVars(document.body);
listScopeVars(document.documentElement);
```

None of them seems to bring the desired result, as they don't even list my global var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a cross domain error because some properties on the window (global) object are not accessible within the iframe, assuming you should be allowed to access the global variable you are trying to read (because its in the iframe itself), you can wrap the inner part of the loop in a try catch block, this way it will continue after getting an access denied.
See code:

```
var listScopeVars = function(scope) {
for (var prop in scope) {
    try{
      if(scope[prop] && typeof(scope[prop]) != "function") {
          console.log(prop + "=" + scope[prop]);
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log("Error: "+e.message);
      //or use
      console.error("Error: "+e.message);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `this` to refer to the global object for your frame.

In other words, do `listScopeVars(this);` inside the iframe.

Comment: It irritates me, but when I do this, I get a cross domain error.